# DWT versus band-pass filter

Tags: filter-design, bandpass, eeg, dwt

Which technique gives better result in extracting a band from a signal, let's say the alpha band (8-13 Hz):  using a band-pass-filter or a DWT (Discrete Wavelet Transformation)?

P.S.: I am working in EEG processing.

Answer (score 1):

With high probability, the band-pass filter.

DWT are invertible non-redundant discrete transformations that decompose data onto iterated low- and high-pass filters. Hence, the bands limits are mostly inverses of powers of two. **So, you cannot chose arbitrary band values with DWT.** More details can be found in the answer to [What are the pros and cons of wavelet for filtering compared to conventional filters?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/43988/15892)

DWT satisfies additional properties (like perfect reconstruction, vanishing moments) that linear filters are not subject to. Hence, **the choice in admissible DWT  filters** is reduced due to these additional constraints.

Hence, for pure band-pass filtering, a carefully designed pure band-filter can always be better than a DWT (and I usually am pro-wavelet). However, one can design a band-pass filter that is way worse than a DWT processing in certain settings.